# How to reduce an array of timestamps to an array of counts of the number of elements within a particular time range

Tags: javascript, arrays, time

I have an array that looks like

```
[
  "2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z"
]
```

And I want to end up with an array of counts of how many timestamps fall into 10 second time ranges.

So for the above example `"2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z"` and `"2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z"` would fall into the range `2017-05-08T13:42:00.000Z` to `2017-05-08T13:42:10.000Z`.

`"2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z"` would fall into the range of `2017-05-08T13:42:10.000Z` to `2017-05-08T13:42:20.000Z`.

`"2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z"`, `"2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z"`, and `"2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z"` would fall into the range of `2017-05-08T13:42:20.000Z` to `2017-05-08T13:42:30.000Z`.

My goal is to get an array of counts of the number of timestamps in each of these ranges. For the above example, the result would be: `[2, 1, 3]`.

Note: I am using Typescript so answers using ES6 features will work.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Hint: Use of es6 [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might be one way to go. But it returns a new array, if that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work using some loops which I am not particularly proud of, but you can change the interval and it can account for more data later if you just use the function called by the forEach on its own.

```js
const timestampsToCheck = [
  "2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z",
  "2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z"
];

let nextTime = null;
let outputTime = [0];

function getNextTime() {
  nextTime.setSeconds(nextTime.getSeconds() + 10);
}

timestampsToCheck.forEach((element) => {

  let thisTime = new Date(element);
  let outputLast = outputTime.length - 1;

  if (nextTime === null) {
    nextTime = thisTime;
    getNextTime();
    outputTime[outputLast]++;
  } else if (thisTime > nextTime) {
    getNextTime();
    while (thisTime > nextTime) {
      getNextTime();
      outputTime.push(0);
    }
    outputTime.push(1);
  } else {
    outputTime[outputLast]++;
  }
});

console.log(outputTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could slice the date and check it with the previous date.

> ```
>           value                  slot           result
> ------------------------  ------------------  ---------
> 2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z  2017-05-08T13:42:0  [1]
> 2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z  2017-05-08T13:42:0  [2]
> 2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z  2017-05-08T13:42:1  [2, 1]
> 2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z  2017-05-08T13:42:2  [2, 1, 1]
> 2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z  2017-05-08T13:42:2  [2, 1, 2]
> 2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z  2017-05-08T13:42:2  [2, 1, 3]
> ```

```js
var data = ["2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z", "2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z", "2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z", "2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z", "2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z", "2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z"],
    count = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (i && aa[i - 1].slice(0, 18) === a.slice(0, 18)) {
            r[r.length - 1]++;
        } else {
            r.push(1);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(count)
```

Comment: This code looks fine however it's strictly hardwired to 10 seconds

Comment: @Redu, 10 seconds is part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
const timestampsToCheck = [
  '2017-05-08T13:42:00.318Z',
  '2017-05-08T13:42:05.590Z',
  '2017-05-08T13:42:12.377Z',
  '2017-05-08T13:42:20.830Z',
  '2017-05-08T13:42:22.634Z',
  '2017-05-08T13:42:25.249Z',
];

const ranges = [
  ['2017-05-08T13:42:00.000Z', '2017-05-08T13:42:10.000Z'],
  ['2017-05-08T13:42:10.000Z', '2017-05-08T13:42:20.000Z'],
  ['2017-05-08T13:42:20.000Z', '2017-05-08T13:42:30.000Z'],
];

const timestampsInRange = ranges.reduce((acc, range) => {
  const count = timestampsToCheck.reduce((innerAcc, time) => {
    return innerAcc + ((time > range[0] && time < range[1]) ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0);
  return acc.concat(count);
}, []);

console.log(timestampsInRange);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tjerwxa/